# AWS S3 Authorization Header InvalidArgument Unsupported Authorization Type with angularJs default header

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3, authorization

I trying to host my old AngularJS app on s3 web static web storage.

Inside my application, I do:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + response.token;
```

So all requests have an Authorization header (includes HTML get)

It was ok on my old hosting way, but on s3, it seems like there is a conflict with s3 authentification that tries to take this token to give access to the HTML file.

S3 response:

```
<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Unsupported Authorization Type
```

Do you know how to change s3 authorization header default name or find a way with AngularJS to not add this token to HTML requests?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you setting an `Authentication` header at all?

Comment: ok change to not used Authentication on html

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to solve this error?

Comment: Sorry I don't remember it :(